# mouse event listeners - on the entire screen?

Tags: c#, java, c++, mouse, mouseevent

I am working on something like the mouse without borders. I want to use a mouse listener on the entire screen. At first I started with Java but it turns out that Java can only detect it in a given frame...
So my question is what language other than Java do you recommend for mouse listeners (on the entire screen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use C#, C/C++ or any other language that provides access to native Win32 APIs you can do this using the [Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) APIs.

For Java, check out [jnativehook](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/).

Comment: Hooks work just fine on background processes that don't have any windows, so I think a console app will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in java as following.
You have to create undecorated transparent JFrame (or instance of Window if you want), so use will not see it but it will exist. Then add mouse listener to this window.

This resource will help you to create transparent windows: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/